# Display in stock variations attributes for variable products in WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I wanted to show on my shop page attributes of available product's variations (ones that are in stock). My code does the work, but instead of attribute names I get attribute's shortened names and it does looks bad. What should I do or change?

This is how the code looks like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_loop_item_stock_notice', 90 );
function display_loop_item_stock_notice() {
    global $product, $wpdb;

    $is_in_stock = $product->is_in_stock();
    $backordered = $product->is_on_backorder();
    
    //Dla wariacji:
    if($product->is_type('variable'))
       {
          $stock_qty = $wpdb->get_var("
          SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
          JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
          WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation'
          AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_parent = '".get_the_id()."'
          AND pm.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL");
        
        //Dla wariacji w magazynie: 
        if($stock_qty > 0)
        {
            echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">  Opcje dostępne z magazynu:</span></br>';
            foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $key['variation_id'] );
            $stock = $variation->get_availability();
            $stock_quantity = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
            if($variation->is_in_stock( ) && $stock_quantity > 0)
            {
            $attr_string = array();
                foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
                    echo $variation->attribute_value;
            }
            echo '<span style="color:green;">'. implode( ', ', $attr_string ). ': ' . $stock_quantity. ' sztuk</span> </br>';}
        }
        }
        //Dla braków na magazynie:
        else
        {
            echo $backordered !== 'no' && $stock_qty <= 0 ? '<span style="color:#33b0c7; "> Dostępny na zamówienie </span>' : '<span style="color:red;"> Brak w magazynie</span>';
        }
}
```

And here is how it looks on shop page:

[variation on shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP4HF.png)

This is how normally attribute options look like:
[variation options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Huo.png)

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following slightly revised code, to get the attribute term name instead of the slug:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_loop_item_stock_notice', 90 );
function display_loop_item_stock_notice() {
    global $product, $wpdb;

    $is_in_stock = $product->is_in_stock();
    $backordered = $product->is_on_backorder();
    
    // Only variable products
    if($product->is_type('variable'))
    {   
        $stock_qty = $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_parent = '".get_the_id()."'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL");
        
        // Variation In Stock 
        if($stock_qty > 0)
        {
            echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">  Opcje dostępne z magazynu:</span></br>';

            foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation_data ) {
                $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_data['variation_id'] );
                $stock = $variation->get_availability();
                $stock_quantity = $variation->get_stock_quantity();

                if($variation->is_in_stock( ) && $stock_quantity > 0) {
                    $attributes = array();

                    foreach ( $variation->get_attributes() as $meta_key => $meta ) {
                        $attributes[] = $variation->get_attribute($meta_key);
                    }
                    echo '<span style="color:green;">'. implode( ', ', $attributes ). ': ' . $stock_quantity. ' sztuk</span> </br>';
                }
            }
        }
        // Variation is not in stock
        else
        {
            echo $backordered !== 'no' && $stock_qty <= 0 ? '<span style="color:#33b0c7; "> Dostępny na zamówienie </span>' : '<span style="color:red;"> Brak w magazynie</span>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).